# SSL handshake error on self-signed cert in Flutter

Tags: android, ssl, flutter

I'm trying to connect server with self-signed cert, but I take error:
E/flutter ( 3781): HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error:

E/flutter ( 3781): CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: Hostname mismatch(ssl_cert.c:345))
Code, where I set cert:

```
String path = '/storage/sdcard0/server.crt';
SecurityContext context = new SecurityContext();
context.setTrustedCertificates(path, password: 'hello');
_client = new HttpClient(context: context);
```

What I'm doing wrong?

If I don't set SecurityContext, I get SSL handshake error.

Comment: Can you post more of your code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I used [HttpClient.badCertificateCallback](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-io/HttpClient/badCertificateCallback.html) 
Here is a code to accept any cert:

```
_client = new HttpClient();
_client.badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
```

Comment: It works, but it doesn't reply to the original question. Accepting all certificates is a bad choice. I bumped into the same problem, and can't understand why setting "setTrustedCertificates" doesn't work.

Comment: I agree with @DmitriiBocharov

Answer (score 6):

You can get a valid SSL certificate for free from https://letsencrypt.org/

Comment: Thanks. Is there any variant to set something like "trust to all certificates" like in java?

Comment: See the other answer. I do wonder, why encrypt if you don't want security -- I can think of a few reasons, but can't tell from your question.

Comment: I'm using self-signed cert for development and in this moment no need to use real certs. HttpClient works with sites with valid certs, I have no problem with them.

Comment: @ArmenKH. which web server you use?

Comment: certbot is such an underrate tool.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I got this error message, because I did not specify hostname when asked for **Common Name**, when creating self signed certificate (*localhost* is OK for simple tests):

```
$ openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout privateKey.key -out certificate.pem

Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:SI
State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:
Locality Name (eg, city) []:
Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:
Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:localhost
Email Address []:
```

Answer (score 0):

download cert.pem

in main.dart

```
final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/certificates/cert.pem');
HttpOverrides.global = CustomHttpOverrides(data);
runApp(...)
```

in CustomHttpOverrides.dart

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

class CustomHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  ByteData data;
  CustomHttpOverrides(this.data);

  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
    final SecurityContext clientContext = SecurityContext()..setTrustedCertificatesBytes(data.buffer.asUint8List());
    return super.createHttpClient(clientContext);
  }
}
```