# Dart SSL certificate generation

Tags: dart, flutter

is it possible to generate SSL certificates with the Dart SDK?
I want this to use in a Flutter app where users can grant other users authority to their own data, kind of.

Thanks in advance.

Theo

Comment: this might be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46135757/ssl-handshake-error-on-self-signed-cert-in-flutter

Comment: Thanks but no, I need to generate certificates using code.

Comment: Use pointyCastles!

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. I suggest simply calling out to a command line utility using dart:io's `Process` class.

```
Process.start('create_certificate', []).then((Process process) {
  ...
});
```