# Flutter Image.network(...) throws HandshakeException

Tags: dart, flutter

I have started working with flutter and dart a few days ago and it's going well so far. Really nice tool, but for the app, I'm building I need a picture from a webserver a whenever I'm trying to call it with `new Image.network(URL)` this exception is thrown:

HandshakeException:

```
Handshake error in client (OS Error: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer certificate(ssl_cert.c:345)).
```

Thanks in advance if anyone could help me.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51081238/995049

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working fine for me

```
var image = new Container(
    width: 100.0,
    height: 100.0,
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(3.0),
      color: const Color(0xff7c94b6),
      image: new DecorationImage(
        image: new NetworkImage(
            "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRwlzVkvBV1EA_w87NFvYAhT-EC2HMRpfTuRFtHE7nXE5GPvnsQ"),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
  );
```

please do check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46234392/2863386) as well to add badCertificateCallback

```
_client = new HttpClient();
_client.badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I found my problem, it was a certificate issue, somehow my app didn't find the right certificate on my phone (maybe because it was seeing it as an emulator?). I tried to do it with the `badCertificateCallback` and a normal `HttpRequest` but couldn't get the image from the data. The server now transmits intermidiate certificates, this fixed the problem for me.

Comment: I tried your code and it worked fine. It was just the server i was asking for the image I guess.

Comment: Agree with @JokingWolf : its better to add the intermediate certificates to the .pem file in the webserver / load balancer terminating SSL connections. Had the same issue with a cert issued by Comodo. My flutter app was failing with the error CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate. Adding intermediate certificates fixed the issue

Answer (score 22):

A way to skip the problem of SSL certification and solve the `Image.network(url)` issue is to use the following code:

```
import 'dart:io';

class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides{
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context){
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port)=> true;
  }
}

void main(){
    HttpOverrides.global = new MyHttpOverrides();
    runApp(new MyApp());
}
```

Comment: That's perfect solution to override for all API calls using HttpClient.

Comment: Doesn't this method create vulnerabilities? man in the middle and stuff.

Comment: Seems like the problem should be solved in the server, instead of doing this.

Comment: !!!this is a bad solution as miguelps points out, should not be used for production code!!!

Comment: In null safety, you should write down the SecurityContext? for type hint

Comment: this was so helpful to me!

Answer (score 2):

I got same issue ! Able to solve it app (It's a server related problem, so Better solve it on server side! )
sol: Add user trust certificate locally ! or skip checking !
I choose to add certificate.
Add your certificate(for your specific domain) as an asset in your pubsec.yaml file. (You can collect it form web browser)

```
assets:
   - assets/raw/certificate.pem
```

Then add the following code somewhere in your application before making network requests. For example, in the main function.

```
void main() async{
 await WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  ByteData data = await 
  rootBundle.load('assets/raw/certificate.pem');
  SecurityContext context = SecurityContext.defaultContext;
  context.setTrustedCertificatesBytes(data.buffer.asUint8List());
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you on Windows and using Kaspersky antivirus? I do not know all the technical details but this antivirus somehow affects the handshake. Disabling it should help.
A similar issue is filed here, though I guess it's not a Dart SDK issue: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/32131

Comment: I am not using Kaspersky thanks for the input though.