# Trying to load an image using NetworkImage fails with CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED for HTTPS site with no certificate

Tags: flutter

In Flutter, trying to load an image from a (development) server (HTTPS without a certificate), using [NetworkImage](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/NetworkImage-class.html) - results in an exception thrown:
Handshake error in client (OS Error: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: ok(handshake.cc:355))

Is there a workaround for this, similar to how it's done in [HTTPClient](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-io/HttpClient/badCertificateCallback.html)?
httpClient.badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;

Comment: Just to keep it simple i'll say no. Try to give the server a valid ssl certificate. There is almost no reason not to. They are free (on certbot) and the instalation is beyond easy! [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/)

Comment: If you can share the Image URL may be we can try to find any workaround.

Comment: Unfortunately not... And it does work with an HTTPS image I've found online

Answer (score 5):

This is for someone who appears here later. I'm just helping others with the full code of NetworkImageSSL as stated by @Alexey (Excellent solution given by him).

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:ui' as ui show instantiateImageCodec, Codec;

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';

class NetworkImageSSL extends ImageProvider<NetworkImageSSL> {
  const NetworkImageSSL(this.url, {this.scale = 1.0, this.headers})
      : assert(url != null),
        assert(scale != null);

  final String url;

  final double scale;

  final Map<String, String> headers;

  @override
  Future<NetworkImageSSL> obtainKey(ImageConfiguration configuration) {
    return new SynchronousFuture<NetworkImageSSL>(this);
  }

  @override
  ImageStreamCompleter load(NetworkImageSSL key, DecoderCallback decode) {
    return MultiFrameImageStreamCompleter(codec: _loadAsync(key), scale: key.scale);
  }

  static final HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient()
    ..badCertificateCallback =
        ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true);

  Future<ui.Codec> _loadAsync(NetworkImageSSL key) async {
    assert(key == this);

    final Uri resolved = Uri.base.resolve(key.url);
    final HttpClientRequest request = await _httpClient.getUrl(resolved);
    headers?.forEach((String name, String value) {
      request.headers.add(name, value);
    });
    final HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
    if (response.statusCode != HttpStatus.ok)
      throw new Exception(
          'HTTP request failed, statusCode: ${response?.statusCode}, $resolved');

    final Uint8List bytes = await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(response);
    if (bytes.lengthInBytes == 0)
      throw new Exception('NetworkImageSSL is an empty file: $resolved');

    return await ui.instantiateImageCodec(bytes);
  }

  @override
  bool operator ==(dynamic other) {
    if (other.runtimeType != runtimeType) return false;
    final NetworkImageSSL typedOther = other;
    return url == typedOther.url && scale == typedOther.scale;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => hashValues(url, scale);

  @override
  String toString() => '$runtimeType("$url", scale: $scale)';
}
```

Comment: i have an error in this line : "  @override
  ImageStreamCompleter load(NetworkImageSSL key) {
    return new MultiFrameImageStreamCompleter(
        codec: _loadAsync(key),
        scale: key.scale,
        informationCollector: (StringBuffer information) {
          information.writeln('Image provider: $this');
          information.write('Image key: $key');
        });
  }"

its saying : This function has a return type of "Iterable<DiagnositcsNode>" but donut ent with a return statement

Comment: @Osman if you're on Master branch then you need to change this method. I've encountered a problem with it too.

My current code is:
`@override
  ImageStreamCompleter load(NetworkImageSSL key) {
    return new MultiFrameImageStreamCompleter(
        codec: _loadAsync(key), scale: key.scale);
  }`

Comment: Should be `@override
  ImageStreamCompleter load(NetworkImageSSL key, DecoderCallback decode) {
    return MultiFrameImageStreamCompleter(codec: _loadAsync(key), scale: key.scale);
  } `

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a simple solution. Just copy and paste the source code of `class NetworkImage` into your code base and modify it to accept any SSL.

It is located in `/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_provider.dart`

Rename it to something like `NetworkImageSSL` to avoid name clash with original class. Then, in this class you'll find

`static final HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();`

Replace it with

`static final HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient()
    ..badCertificateCallback =
    ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true);`

Include the necessary packages before you compile (you can copy relevant imports from `image_provider.dart`). Now you can load images as follows:

`new Image(image: NetworkImageSSL(thumbURL), fit: BoxFit.cover)`

Answer (score 3):

Taken from [here](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/flutter/flutter/19588/531491751)

```
class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides{
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext context){
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port)=> true;
  }
}

void main(){
    HttpOverrides.global = new MyHttpOverrides();
    runApp(new MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In file _network_image_io.dart 
find

```
  static HttpClient get _httpClient {
HttpClient client = _sharedHttpClient;
assert(() {
  if (debugNetworkImageHttpClientProvider != null)
    client = debugNetworkImageHttpClientProvider();
  return true;
}());
return client;}
```

and change it to

```
  static HttpClient get _httpClient {
HttpClient client = _sharedHttpClient
  ..badCertificateCallback =
  ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true);
assert(() {
  if (debugNetworkImageHttpClientProvider != null)
    client = debugNetworkImageHttpClientProvider();
  return true;
}());
return client;}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you get null safety error with that above codes, try this in "_network_image_io.dart"

```
    static HttpClient get _httpClient {
    HttpClient client = _sharedHttpClient
      ..badCertificateCallback =
          ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true);
    assert(() {
      if (debugNetworkImageHttpClientProvider != null)
        client = debugNetworkImageHttpClientProvider!();//only change is "!()"
      return true;
    }());
    return client;
  }
```