# Image.network certificate error CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error

Tags: flutter, dart, ssl

I'm building a Flutter (3.16.12) app and I'm facing a problem with Image.network on Android both ADV or real device (did not try on iPhone yet).

I need to display a remote image using Image.network widget from a customer remote server. The problem is I keep getting the following error:

> Handshake error in client (OS Error: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED:
> Hostname mismatch(handshake.cc:393))

If my research was correct the problem is a misconfiguration of the remote server SSL certificates, but I cannot get the customer's IT to fix that as they state the images are perfectly accessible via browsers or other https requests other than Flutter (I confirm that).

I know I could globally disable all SSL checks so I visited one of those images from the browser and saved the certificate and tried.

```
ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/certs/servername.com.pem');

SecurityContext context = SecurityContext.defaultContext;

context.setTrustedCertificatesBytes(data.buffer.asUint8List());
```

Even by ignoring such code poses a security risk, this didn't work.

I also tried to create a customized ImageProvider class by modifying the original code so that it ignores the SSL error but did not manage to get it working. The following code from image network provider modified widget doesn't rise an error but doesn't display the image too:

```
static final HttpClient _httpclient = new HttpClient()

   ..badCertificateCallback = ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) {

   debugPrint("CSS Error customer");

   return true;

});
```

As requested here an url of an image I'm referring to:

> https://evolutionfitImg_orange.teamsystem.com/imgEsercizi/197284_56277_esercizioB.jpg

Is there a solution so that I can disable those checks, better if for those images only, and get those network images to show in some ways?

Comment: Here is the answer ->https://stackoverflow.com/a/60019856/17568395

Comment: Are you certain you are using the correct hostname? (You are getting hostname mismatch.) Confirm that there's no redirection going on. Open one of the images in a browser (as suggested by IT) and click the padlock. View the server's certificate. Check the Common Name and the Subject Alternate Name(s). Update the question with screenshots of the server's certificate. Update the question with a test image we can try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @RifatHossain this is not an acceptable solution, it disables security check for the whole app and so it poses huge security risks.

Comment: @RichardHeap yes, as I mentioned the images are perfectly accessilbe and marked as secure  via browser or via ajax calls from node (as an example).

Comment: Please update the question with the information requested.

Comment: Also note that the linked solution isn't as bad as you think. Note that the callback is the `badCertificateCallback`. So that means that good certificates are already handled by the lower layers. Where a certificate cannot be handled (i.e. name mismatch, expiration date, signed by an untrusted authority) then the callback happens. It's up to you to inspect the actual server certificate (first parameter) to decide whether you want to accept it. There's no reason why you couldn't perform the subject name match yourself - and restrict it to just the troublesome server's URL.

Comment: Just want to emphasize that what Richard said is correct. The problem is that your code is *not* using the same hostname to reference the remote image as you are using in your browser experiments.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk what do you mean by "your code is not using the same hostname"? I'm talking about an app, not a website. I doubt it's a cors problem, I fetch lot fo data (including images) from different domains in the same app.

Comment: @RichardHeap the certificate is issued for _.domainname.com and I'm fetching the image from what it looks like a subdomain (see edited content). This could be the problem, but yet I cannot do anything about it as the browser (used just to check, I'm developing an app) doesn't blink an eye when displaying such images.

Comment: When the bad certificate callback is called, what is the value of the `host` argument?

Answer (score 1):

For some strange reason the underlying Dart SSL implementation (boringssl) isn't matching the hostname with the wildcard Subject Alterative Name (SAN) in the certificate.

As noted in the comments, you can safely provide a `badCertificateCallback` to check for this special case yourself. (Note that the callback is NOT called normally when the SSL implementation is able to match the hostnames, expiration dates etc itself.)

I tested the following simple implementation and it works. You can obviously add extra checks of expiration date, cert pinning, etc., yourself.

```
// a callback that accepts bad certs if and only if it's the teamsystem wildcard and the request was to a teamsystem host
badCertificateCallback = ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) {
      return cert.subject.toLowerCase().endsWith('*.teamsystem.com') &&
          host.toLowerCase().endsWith('.teamsystem.com');
    })
```