# Flutter - How to get api response from a certification errored link

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to get an api from [www.mocky.io](http://www.mocky.io), the issue is, when the app starts I'm getting an error like

`E/flutter (  846): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: 
E/flutter (  846):  CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer certificate(handshake.cc:354))`

*this is  how I'm getting the response.*

```
  Future _fetchPost() async {
http.Response response = await http.get(url);

print(response.body);

setState(() {
  var convertDatatoJson = json.decode(response.body);
  debugPrint(convertDatatoJson.toString());
  _data = convertDatatoJson['table_menu_list'];
});}
```

How can I verify the certificate for this api link for GET method?

I referred this issue, for POST method https://stackoverflow.com/a/54359013/11893608,

any other suggestions would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change https to http

it will Resolve your Issue

Use this :         http://www.mocky.io/v2/5dfccffc310000efc8d2c1ad

Comment: there is no https

Comment: paste the API here

Comment: Use this :         http://www.mocky.io/v2/5dfccffc310000efc8d2c1ad

Comment: i tried already and I'm getting the response, but why I couldn't get the response in https.upvoted();

Answer (score 1):

Try adding both `http` and `www.`

**Example:**

```
http://www.mocky.io/v2/5185415ba171ea3a00704eed
```

`mocky.io` may be using `www` to differentiate between subdomains. That is why its not worked when adding `http` only.

Comment: Thank you for saying this specifically but I need the certification to be ignored while calling the api. Is there any way? upvoted();

Comment: @AllwiN I don't know how to ignore this with `http` package. But you can do it by directly using `HttpClient` class. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46135757/ssl-handshake-error-on-self-signed-cert-in-flutter)