# I have this problem when i try to GetData From Mysql in flutter Handshake error in client (OS ErrorWRONG_VERSION_NUMBER(tls_record.cc:242)

Tags: mysql, json, database, flutter, handshake

[image: image for the problem]

part of code

```
Future getData() async {
    var url = Uri.parse("https://10.0.2.2:8000/drop/");
    var res = await http.get(url);
    var resb = jsonDecode(res.body);
    return (resb);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe its a `http` , `https` problem
did you try it like this without parsing the url ?

```
Future getData() async {
    var res = await http.get("https://10.0.2.2:8000/drop/");
    var resb = jsonDecode(res.body);
    return (resb);
```

or like this :

```
Future getData() async {
    var url = Uri.tryParse("https://10.0.2.2:8000/drop/");
    var res = await http.get(url);
    var resb = jsonDecode(res.body);
    return (resb);
```

also this happens when an `HTTPS` client reaches an `HTTP` endpoint

Comment: in first answer its give me a Uri problem
and in the next one its give me same my problem

Answer (score 0):

it should be with htos

```
var url = Uri.https('10.0.2.2:8000', 'drop/')
```

see [manual](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data)

Comment: my guess is that your certificate doesn't support tls 1.2, what happens if you open it in a browser?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46135757/ssl-handshake-error-on-self-signed-cert-in-flutter confirms it, your selfsigned certificate isn't correct

Comment: its give problem in a browser too .. how i make it support tls 1.2 ??

Comment: as i don't know what you did, i can even postulate a solution, maybe you haven't the right key https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16480846/x-509-private-public-key  or you didn't bind the key to the port.

Comment: its work for a link online but doesn't for Localhost

Comment: online most have a valid ssl certificate, at localhost you need to bind it to work https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-configure-a-port-with-an-ssl-certificate